# Open PDF in default viewer from DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have a grid that displays a name & link to all of the pdf files in a folder. The link opens the file in the browser.

This is not ideal because the browser caches the files, so if a document is moved or changed, the old cached version is still accessible.

Would it be possible to have the link open the file in the default installed pdf viewer and avoid caching completely?

Here is my Grid code:

```
<form runat="server">
Search for a file: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFilter" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnShow"
        runat="server" Text="Display" onclick="btnShow_Click" />
</form>


<asp:DataGrid runat="server" id="FileList" Font-Name="Verdana" CellPadding="5"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#eeeeee"
HeaderStyle-BackColor="Navy" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
HeaderStyle-Font-Size="15pt" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="True">
<Columns>
<asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="Name" DataTextField="Name" 
       HeaderText="File Name" target="_blank"/>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="LastWriteTime" HeaderText="Last Write Time"
    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
</Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

CS:

```
protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     ShowData();
    }

    public void ShowData()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(""));

        FileInfo[] info = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.pdf");            //Get FileInfo and Save it a FileInfo[] Array

        List<Getfiles> _items = new List<Getfiles>();          // Define a List with Two coloums

        foreach (FileInfo file in info) //Loop the FileInfo[] Array
           _items.Add(new Getfiles { Name = file.Name, LastWriteTime = file.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") });  // Save the Name and LastwriteTime to List


        var tlistFiltered1 = _items.Where(item => item.Name.Contains(txtFilter.Text)); // Find the file that Contains Specific word in its File Name

        FileList.DataSource = tlistFiltered1; //Assign the DataSource to DataGrid
        FileList.DataBind();

    }

    public class Getfiles
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastWriteTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: My default pdf viewer is Google Chrome... so for me it might not work either way. Maybe you can somehow disable caching for your pdfs at webserver level instead?

Comment: @nvoigt Can that be done? Wouldn't my browser still cache even if you made a server level change? I use Chrome as well.

Answer (score 0):

Better you Prompt a dialog to User and ask him to download the file, then it will avoid caching in Browser...

Try like below...

**HTML :**

`Change the DataGrid HyperLinkColumn` like below :

```
<asp:HyperLinkColumn DataNavigateUrlField="Name" DataTextField="Name" 
       HeaderText="File Name" target="_blank"  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Download.aspx?FileName={0}" />
```

Then `Add a New .aspx page` to your Website and named it as **Download.aspx**...

and On the `Page load event` of `Download.aspx` write the below code..

**C# :**

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string FName = Server.MapPath(@"Files\" + Request.QueryString["FileName"].ToString());
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FName);
            Response.TransmitFile(FName);
            Response.End(); 
        }
```

Comment: This does work to avoid caching, but it creates a copy of the document on the machine of every user that downloads it, which isn't ideal. It is still an option. Do I need to look for an open source pdf web viewer and find a way of passing the document to that?

Comment: Do you think the pdf would be cached if it was in an iFrame?